# Looking for a supplement to my Projective Geometry course

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, book-recommendation

this is my first time posting to Math Stack Exchange!

So currently, I am taking a Projective Geometry course and I am struggling. I was wondering if anyone knew of any textbook I could read to help with this course. I am looking for something not too dense (but it is not a requirement), and basically something that could lead me into an understanding of projective geometry.

I only know basic Linear Algebra and I am currently taking a more extensive, applied linear algebra class alongside this one. So I am struggling because most of the concepts being introduced to me are concepts that were only covered for a second at the end of my basic linear algebra course, two years ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to surpass Coxeter:

> [Projective Geometry](http://books.google.com/books/about/Projective_Geometry.html?id=gjAAI4FW0tsC).

---

[image: GoogleImage]

---

For a more modern and more advanced approach, see Richter-Gebert's

> [Perspectives on Projective Geometry: A Guided Tour Through Real and Complex Geometry](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-3-642-17285-4).

---

[image: R-GFig1.1]

---

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Would it be useful if I start with Coxeter and then make my way into Richter-Gebert?